# Android Notifications - Both if/else part running

Tags: android, notifications, multiple-instances

I am implementing a notification in my application ( xmpp chat ) with a packet listener.

Till the time the first notification comes the code works fine, but as soon as the person clicks on the notification, then after the first click both the code of ( if and else ) is running out. I am not able to get the solution and its strange also HOW BOTH IF/ELSE code is running - AFTER FIRST NOTIFICATION CLICK.

code

```
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        final PacketCollector collector = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packetChat) {
                Message message = (Message) packetChat;
                packetChat = collector.nextResult();

                if (message.getBody() != null) {

                    fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                            .getFrom());
                    Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody()
                            + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
                    // messages.add(fromName + ":");
                    mMessageItem = new MessageItemDataClass();
                    mMessageItem.isSendMessage = false;
                    mMessageItem.messageText = message.getBody();
                    messages.add(mMessageItem);


                    //to add the packet message in the layout only when the user is on the same friend's screen
                    //for anonymous chat
                    if(packetChat.getFrom().equalsIgnoreCase(refineFromjId(frienduserID)+"/Smack")){



                        messages.add(mMessageItem);
                    }
                    else{
                        if(checkPresence=true){
                        notificationforChat(fromName.substring(0,fromName.indexOf("@"))+":1212 "+message.getBody(),packetChat.getFrom(),0);
                        }
                    }

                    //messages.add(mMessageItem);
                    // Add the incoming message to the list view
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //simply turn around to the last of the screen
                            mList.setSelection(mList.getCount());

                            lastIndex = mList.getLastVisiblePosition()+1;
                            if (mList.getFirstVisiblePosition() > lastIndex || mList.getLastVisiblePosition() <= lastIndex) {
                                //mList.smoothScrollToPosition(lastIndex);
                                customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                mList.setSelection(mList.getCount());

                                dbhHelper.close();

                            }else{
                                mList.setSelection(mList.getCount());
                                customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                dbhHelper.close();

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }               
        }, filter);
```

Notification

```
public void notificationforChat(CharSequence message,String toJid, int notificationID) {

        int notificationCount = 1;
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        CharSequence tickerText = message;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        //notification.number = notificationCount++;
        Context context = getApplicationContext();



        CharSequence contentTitle = "Chat";
        CharSequence contentText = message;
        Intent notificationIntentforChat = new Intent(this, UserChatActivity.class);
        notificationIntentforChat.putExtra("userNameVal", toJid);       
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntentforChat, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
                contentIntent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;   
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);
    }
```

Please help me if anybody can!
Thanks

Comment: sorry, noob/lazy question - which of two if/else is running simultaneously? and do you have a logcat for this?

Comment: I think multiple instance are being created when notification is clicked, if/else which has notificatioforChat code is running simultaneously - but when I debug it it don't enters in the both. So it seems that multiple instance are being created which makes it to look like as both are running simultaneaously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function might be called more than once (may be twice) at the same time with different conditions...so you will be getting the feeling of if and else getting called. Try using a flag to limit the number of times that code block is executed or set a counter to check whether the code block is executed more than once. Make the counter or flag variable that you are planning to use as static so that you can detect the call from different instances that you might be creating unknowingly.

Comment: Yes I have checked my function is running twice, it is listening to the same packets twice :( now I am in a problem why these packets are receiving multiple times ( after first click ) this is the main prblm. that multiple instances are forming

Comment: Please help me. Its the problem of multiple instance formation when I click the notifcaions

Comment: I have not found the soln yet

Comment: I've put a solution for the same question in the new question you have posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411173/android-multiple-instances